# Variable dynamically assigned with nth-child

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to do a pretty simple task with SASS : 
I'd like all my `h2` and `strong` tags inside an odd `<li>` element to have some color, otherwise if it's an even `<li>` they would get another color.

I did this but it's not working only the first color is effective (cf5d18) :

```
li{
    $color: #cf5d18;

    &:nth-child(odd){
        $color: #739337;
    }

    h2{
        font-size: 1.7em;
        color: $color;
    }

    strong{
       color: $color;
    }

}
```

Do you guys know how I could handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't work that way - the odd/even test happens in the browser, at render time. The variable has one value or another regardless of that.

I'd go the more-straightforward route:

```
$evencolor: #cf5d18;
$oddcolor: #739337;

li {
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
  }

  h2, strong {
    color: $evencolor;
  }

  &:nth-child(odd) {
    h2, strong {
      color: $oddcolor;
    }
  }
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ZYwdzE

Comment: Ok, I understand better now, I didn't realized :nth-child was tested at render time .. Thanks for your quick answer :) !